# WCF Multiple OperationContracts for one Service

Tags: wcf

In WCF is this legal?

I would like to do two services with one svc file. How do I configure my endpoints in the client?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuditLog
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Log(int AuditTypeID, string UserName, string ImpersonatingForUserName, string Action);

    [OperationContract]
    string PageLog(int PageActionID, string UserName, string ItemName, string Value, string Operation);
}
```

Then in my svc file

```
public class AuditLog : IAuditLog
{
     public bool Log(int AuditTypeID, string UserName, string ImpersonatingForUserName, string Action)
     {
        .....
     }

     public string PageLog(int PageActionID, string UserName, string ItemName, string Value, string Operation)
     {
         .....
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have multiple OperationContracts per [service contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733070(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Services expose a number of operations. In Windows Communication
>   Foundation (WCF) applications

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734686(v=vs.110).aspx) - an example with an interface that defines the contract and the implementation of the interface.

```
// IService1.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace GettingStartedLib
{
        [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
        public interface ICalculator
        {
            [OperationContract]
            double Add(double n1, double n2);
            [OperationContract]
            double Subtract(double n1, double n2);
            [OperationContract]
            double Multiply(double n1, double n2);
            [OperationContract]
            double Divide(double n1, double n2);
        }
}

// Service1.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace GettingStartedLib
{
    public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 + n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Add({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            // Code added to write output to the console window.
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }

        public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 - n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Subtract({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }

        public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 * n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Multiply({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }

        public double Divide(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 / n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Divide({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```